# how to execute struts tags inside js file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am able to execute struts tags code in following manner. But the same code when I put inside js file, it does not work. Please help

```
 <script language='JavaScript' type='text/JavaScript'>
var a, b;
<s:iterator value="abclist" var="myBean">
    a = '<s:property value="#myBean.a"/>';
    b = '<s:property value="#myBean.b"/>';
</s:iterator>
```

Comment: You are using struts tag in java-script file might be that is causing issue and Now in java-script file you have to get the list like `var bbb = document.getElementById("myValue").value;` this link might help[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8400429/struts-tags-in-javascript]

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to avoid this type of approach. As it is can have strange side effects and reduce legibility of the javascript. I'd prefer using a ajax request to get data and consume it in my JS.

But if you want to generate dynamic js files with struts you will have to configure the struts to process urls that point to js files or return "application/javascript" content-type from a struts processed url and use it as a script.

This answer explains how to configure content-type of response:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1683169/1496916

```
<action name="..." class="...">
  <result name="SUCCESS">
    <param name="contentType">application/javascript</param>
```

Then just use this action as a `src` in a `script` tag .